# Passenger showing blank 200 OK responses when it should be showing 404sA

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

(Using Rails 2.3.9 and this happens both with passenger-2.2.15 and passenger-3.0.0.pre3.)

Does any know how I could be getting blank pages with status 200 for requests that should result in 404s? I see in log/staging.log ActionController::RoutingError... but in my passenger access.log it's showing 200 OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops. This was a problem with Facebooker's `pretty_errors` setting.